# jax rs service on wildfly doesn't seem reachable?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, wildfly

When deploying a jax-rs service on wildfly, I keep getting a 404 not found.

My webservice class:

```
package org.declercq.reportbuilderback.webservices;

import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.declercq.reportbuilderback.dao.UserDao;
import org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.User;

@RequestScoped
@Path("/users")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class UserWebService {

@GET
    @Path("/all")
    public List<User> listAll() {
        //TODO: retrieve the users 
        System.out.println("Here");
        final List<User> users = new UserDao().getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("Here 2");
        return users;
    }
}
```

My Application class:

```
package org.declercq.reportbuilderback.webservices;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

}
```

My pom.xml with all dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.declercq.reportbuilderback</groupId>
    <artifactId>reportbuilderback</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
            message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
            tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom>8.2.1.Final</version.jboss.bom>

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill
                of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
                of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
                of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can
                read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools
                for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
                stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
                from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-resteasy</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
            of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
            as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
            in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

        <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
            typesafe criteria queries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
            annotations are incorrectly used. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
                just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
                tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The output from my server:

```
17:15:02,644 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
17:15:04,564 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
17:15:05,038 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
17:15:13,537 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found reportbuilderback.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called reportbuilderback.war.dodeploy
17:15:13,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:15:13,697 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
17:15:13,734 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
17:15:13,853 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:15:13,862 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
17:15:13,871 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:15:13,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
17:15:13,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
17:15:13,908 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
17:15:13,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
17:15:13,947 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
17:15:14,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
17:15:14,768 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
17:15:14,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
17:15:14,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgres
17:15:15,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
17:15:15,076 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:15:15,353 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
17:15:15,643 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
17:15:15,769 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
17:15:15,774 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
17:15:15,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
17:15:15,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
17:15:16,205 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
17:15:16,367 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/PostGreDS]
17:15:16,951 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
17:15:17,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
17:15:17,089 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "reportbuilderback.war" (runtime-name: "reportbuilderback.war")
17:15:17,771 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
17:15:17,866 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
17:15:17,879 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
17:15:17,884 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
17:15:17,886 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
17:15:17,894 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
17:15:17,895 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
17:15:17,900 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
17:15:18,673 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
17:15:19,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary
17:15:20,345 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'reportbuilderback.war#primary'
17:15:20,530 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: primary
    ...]
17:15:20,662 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment reportbuilderback.war
17:15:21,231 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.10.Final}
17:15:21,232 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
17:15:21,235 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
17:15:21,238 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
17:15:21,407 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
17:15:22,103 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
17:15:22,669 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'reportbuilderback.war#primary'
17:15:22,848 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
17:15:22,850 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/reportbuilderwebservices]
17:15:22,851 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=reportbuilderwebservices, password=****}
17:15:22,852 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
17:15:22,855 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
17:15:23,194 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
17:15:23,662 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
17:15:23,666 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@24d10442
17:15:23,691 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Envers integration enabled? : true
17:15:24,626 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
17:15:26,165 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context '/reportbuilderback'
17:15:26,993 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /reportbuilderback
17:15:27,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "reportbuilderback.war" (runtime-name : "reportbuilderback.war")
17:15:27,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
17:15:27,422 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
17:15:27,422 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 27185ms - Started 422 of 670 services (404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I access the webservice using http://localhost:8080/reportbuilderback/rest/users/all, however every time I'm getting a 404 not found.
If you look in my webservice function for listing all users, I put a System.out.println in there. But when accessing this URL, it even never gets printed to console, so it seems the service is never contacted...

There is also a webpage at  http://localhost:8080/reportbuilderback/index.jsf, which I can access just perfectly, it's purely the rest webservices that are not found...

Am I missing something here?

UPDATE:
Also tried explicitly adding the class in Application-subclass:

```
package org.declercq.reportbuilderback.webservices;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.User;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.User.class);
        return s;
    }


}
```

Still not working, getting a "not found", nothing printed to console.

UPDATE2:
To be sure also added an empty web.xml to my WEB-INF folder, still the same: jsf page works, rest webservice doesn't work...

UPDATE3:
Noticed something else too upon further investigation: when I enter an incorrect URL, I get a "404 not found" from Wildfly on screen. However, when I try to access the webservice, I'm getting a "Not found" on screen, without the 404 code.

UPDATE4:
Info for application context path from wildfly admin console:

```
reportbuilderback.war

  Deployment is enabled

Details

    Last enabled at 2016-11-02 08:34:05,097 CET
    The deployment was never disabled
    Runtime name: reportbuilderback.war

Content:  {"archive" => false,"path" => "deployments/reportbuilderback.war","relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir"}

Disabled time:      

Disabled timestamp:     

Enabled:    true

Enabled time:  1478072045097

Enabled timestamp:   2016-11-02 08:34:05,097 CET

Name:     reportbuilderback.war

Owner:  ("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner") ("scanner" => "default")

Persistent:    false

Runtime name:  reportbuilderback.war

Status:   OK
```

Comment: Your application context path might be different. I think that /rest/users/all is correct. However, the reportbuilderback part might not be. This part should be the name of the artifact (war), without the .war suffix. You can go to wildfly administration console and have a look in Deployments section what context path is your deployed application available at.

Comment: @ThePaul thanks, updated my initial post with the info from the admin console. Seems that the application context path is indeed /reportbuilderback/<everythingelsehere>? Keep in mind, as I said in my post, http://localhost:8080/reportbuilderback/index.jsf does work. It's the webservice that I can't reach for some reason...

Comment: Als, @ThePaul, just noticed that my server output of deployment that I listed above states:
17:15:26,993 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /reportbuilderback
17:15:27,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "reportbuilderback.war" (runtime-name : "reportbuilderback.war")

Comment: Good, it is indeed the name of the war.

Comment: Yep, see my post below. Now for some obscure reason it suddenly works and I didn't change anything... No idea what kind of weird side effect I was having.

Comment: Strange. Maybe browser cache ? Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what just happened, but I just restarted my entire dev machine and now suddenly it works, without having changed anything...

Comment: I am facing an exactly same problem, I try restarting everything but it didn't help...Did u find any specific reason for this issue?

Comment: I've been learning some of spring and spring-boot. I lost hours trying to deploy an app to wildfly.
That's it I am moving to spring and to the hell Java EE and Jackarta EE and All the crapy specs and Application Servers.

Answer (score 0):

after I updated wildfly from 10 to 20, web services just don't work anymore.
Any http request returns `404 not found`
The long don't even show any service registration as it used to

```
Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class app.rapidoc.RestActivator$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
```

The problem was the following dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I had to add a scope provided to make things work

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- ADDED THIS LINE -->
        <version>4.7.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope this will help some of you.
Salam.